# Unable to fetch data from URL of video Asset from Photos framework

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, photosframework

I'm stuck with this error.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_4156.MP4”
>   couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
>
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/104APPLE/IMG_4156.MP4,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x160ebd8f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}}

I'm trying to extract Data from a url of video asset from the Photo's framework which is something like this :
 file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/104APPLE/IMG_4155.MP4

However I m successful in extracting photos using the same method not the videos..

I m using these lines to extract the video :

```
let urlNew = URL(fileURLWithPath: item.finalVideoForServer)
let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: urlNew)
```

Kindly help me or correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Don't load all your movie into memory. Why do you need the movie data?

Comment: I have a set of 5-6 videos needed temporarily. Shall i rather use the document directory instead to store them locally and then access them?

Comment: Yes just save them locally

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following lines to your info.plist file(open in source code view) in your project directory

```
<!--  Photo Library -->
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use</string>

<!--  Camera -->
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use</string>
```

Comment: already there buddy. Still not able to access. Sandbox issue i believe.